# SQL Plus- no rows selected error;though the data has been inserted without any error

Tags: oracle10g, sqlplus

I am a very newbie with this ***SQL Plus and Oracle 10g*** thing.So,please don't mind the stupid questions.

See, what problem I am facing is that whenever i fire a query over a table;

`SELECT * FROM emp;`

The output comes out to be "**no rows selected**".

I am in utter dilemma as the table and its schema is clearly preserved but the data which I entered is not getting displayed. The same is happening for all the user generated tables. The tuples are not getting displayed. Is this the problem related to **SQL Plus**???
Kindly help and give me a proper guide.

Comment: `no rows selected` simply means that your table `emp` has no record at all. Are you sure your `emp` table has record in it?

Comment: But,I have successfully inserted the data into the table using 'insert into' commands.

Comment: How are you "entering data"?  Are you sure those inserts are being committed?

Comment: How to get to know whether the input data are committed or not???

Comment: Can you check your table using GUI (if any)? Moreover, when you inserted data using `insert into emp` did it output saying `x rows affected` where x is number of rows.

Comment: @shekhar - Did you (or the application that is running the `insert` statement) explicitly issue a `commit`?

Comment: Yeah,the Oracle database apex application shows that there is no data present in this table. So, now my question is that why the creation and deletion of DML commands are occuring without commit;whereas  the DDL commands need to be committed???
How to check this or way to get rid of this issue?
Also,please elaborate the 'commit' point in detail and with a proper answer below,if possible.

Comment: @JustinCave - How to check that or where to scrutinise???

Comment: @Rahul - No,this point that it did not mention that' x number of rows affected.' is a bit helpful for you people,I hope so!

Comment: @shekhar - I think you have that the wrong way around; DDL (like `create table` implicitly commits, but DML (like `insert`) does not. Are you inserting the data in one client, like SQL*Plus, and then querying it in a different client, like Apex, or even just in a different session of the same client? If so, in the client/session that did the `insert` statement, just do `commit;`, and also re-run the query from that session. Please update the question to say exactly what commands you have issued in each client, and what response you got.

Comment: @Alex Poole - Oh man,your suggestion of externally providing commit has worked and now the data has been inserted.
But,can you describe that why do we need to externally put over a commit,whereas in my MySQL session,I never faced this situation. It by default committed the query fired. Please help here as this is creating tension.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Adding to my frustration, the query--->>> SELECT * FROM emp where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(hiredate,'DD-MON-YY')) between 1980 and 1990; is again displaying no rows selected;though there are sufficient data. Kindly resolve this issue. Totally agitated over this topic!!!

Comment: That's a whole separate issue. But (a) don't call `to_date()` against something that is already a `date`; and (b) don't use `YY`, use `YYYY` or (as a Y2K-safer option) `RR` or `RRRR`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Oracle, every statement that you issue is part of a transaction.  Those transactions need to either be committed (in which case the changes are made permanent) or rolled back (in which case the changes are reverted) before another session can see the data.  Some databases either do not support transactions (i.e. MyISAM tables in MySQL) or do not implicitly start transactions (i.e. SQL Server).  The Oracle approach is generally far superior-- when you inadvertently run a `delete` statement that is missing an important predicate, the ability to rollback the operation when it deletes many more rows that you are expecting can be a real career saver.

In Oracle, when you've run whatever statements comprise your transaction and you are confident that your changes are correct, you need to explicitly issue a `commit` to make those changes visible to other sessions, i.e.

```
SQL> insert into some_table( <<columns>> ) values( <<values>> );
SQL> insert into some_other_table( <<columns>> ) values ( <<more values>> );
SQL> commit;
```

If you are really, really, really sure that you prefer the behavior you might be accustomed to in other tools, you can tell SQL*Plus to autocommit your changes

```
SQL> set autocommit on;
SQL> <<do whatever>>
```

That is generally a really bad idea.  The tiny benefit you get from not having to explicitly issue a `commit` is far outweighed by the ability to ensure that other sessions don't see data in an inconsistent state (i.e. if your transferring money from account A to account B by issuing two update statements, you don't want someone seeing an intermediate result where either both accounts have the money or neither account does) and the ability to rollback a change if it turns out to do something other than what you expected.

Comment: Oh,this tiny piece of job can cost me this much of pain !!!
Thanks to point out at a peculiar misunderstanding;I was just cursing SQL Plus because of its this behaviour, I could have thought over the AUTOCOMMIT status myself!
Anyways Thanks a Lot...